# What is 前源? If not the 'spring ahead'?

Tags: translation, meaning

Here are some random sentences

> 海上画派的前源是以董其昌为代表的松江画派。
>
> 他在师从鲁风老师的同时，亦在不停的上溯花鸟画艺术的前源，寻找滋养，丰盈自我素养，这就使其花鸟画作品逐步凸显出章法的大开大合，用笔则更加强化了 ...
>
> ... 也就是说，商代后期的殷墟文化应当另有其本土前源。

I'm thinking it is some art term that I'm not familiar with.

It certainly is not the same as the 前源 that appears in《望梅止渴》, which just means *the spring ahead*...

so what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence:

前源 = original source/source ahead

so it translates to ...**originated from**...

前源 in 望梅止渴 doesn't necessarily mean spring ahead, because 源 in 望梅止渴 is 水源(water source). So 前源 in 望梅止渴 means 前面的水源(water **source** ahead), where source is the definition of 源.

It could be anything, for example Japanese Kanji的前源是Chinese Hanzi.